# If string is a number convert to float otherwise put in new column

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame( data = {"CouponCode": ["1","2","3","Winter14","5"] } )
```

I want to take the above data frame and get the below dataframe. I want all the numbers in the CouponCode column to be converted to floats or ints and if the value is not a number I want to put it in a new column name couponName (I put in "nan" as strings, but of course I want them to be 'real' nulls).

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame(data = {"CouponCode": [1,2,3,"Winter14",5], "CouponName": ["nan", "nan", "nan", "Winter14", "nan"]} )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***plan***

- use `pd.to_numeric` applied to every individual element of `'CouponCode'`.  This is slow!  Why do I do it?  Because it's the only way I know of to ensure that `int` gets mapped to `int`, `float` to `float`, and `str` to `str`.  `dtype` of resultant column will be `object`.  I could have done a `pd.to_numeric` on the entire column with `errors='coerce'`, the problem is that the `nan` would convert `int` to `float`.
- use `.str.is_numeric` to determine which are strings, and port those over to the new column.

---

```
df.loc[~df.CouponCode.astype(str).str.isnumeric(), 'CouponName'] = df.CouponCode
df.loc[:, 'CouponCode'] = df.CouponCode.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
df

  CouponCode CouponName
0          1        NaN
1          2        NaN
2          3        NaN
3   Winter14   Winter14
4          5        NaN
```

---

```
df.to_dict('list')

{'CouponCode': [1, 2, 3, 'Winter14', 5],
 'CouponName': [nan, nan, nan, 'Winter14', nan]}
```

Comment: I am getting this error: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'. How can I fix that?

Comment: @Hound see if you get same error running just `~df.CouponCode.str.isnumeric()` on dataframe prior to any other adjustments.

Comment: @Hound it's because you already have some floats or ints in your column. **work around**  `~df.CouponCode.astype(str).str.isnumeric()`

Answer (score 2):

Use `.str` accessor with `isnumeric()`:

```
df['CouponName']=np.where(~df.CouponCode.str.isnumeric(),df.CouponCode,np.nan)
```

Output:

```
  CouponCode CouponName
0          1        NaN
1          2        NaN
2          3        NaN
3   Winter14   Winter14
4          5        NaN
```